# how to using svg fonts to draw a text

Tags: python-3.x, svg

I'm using python and SvgWrite lib, I have also converted a Tff font in SVG format, I'd like to create a text with this font avoiding text element, I mean char by char because I want, rotate and scale every single char separately.

I dunno how to achieve this because if I write

```
dwg.add(dwg.text("test", insert=(10, 10), font_size="20px", fill="black"))
```

will be translated to this

```
<text fill="black" font-size="20px" x="10" y="10">test</text>
```

I also avoid to embedded entirely set of fonts.

Comment: you just want to create every letter as a separate tspan within the text element no? See https://svgwrite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/classes/text.html for tspan creation.

Comment: Could you write what you would like your final html to look like? This seems like less of a Python question as an html question.

Comment: no, the text is for a captcha so I don't want to make readable content

Comment: Stevej I have to generate in realtime with python on Django framework